# How to use ternaty operator inside expect (Jest)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, tdd

I need to check if service properties does not undefined get value from action , otherway set 0. How to use ternaty operator inside expect?

```
it('SET_CURRENT_SERVICE', () => {
    const action = {
      type: SET_CURRENT_SERVICE,
      service: {
        minAmount: 111,
        maxAmount: 1231
      }
    }

    expect(payment(defaultState, action)).toEqual({
      ...defaultState,
      minAmount: (typeof minAmount !== 'undefined' ? Number(action.service.minAmount) : 0),
      maxAmount: (typeof maxAmount !== 'undefined' ? Number(action.service.maxAmount) : 0),
    });
  })
```

here is an error:

[image]

Comment: Where is the variable `minAmount` & `maxAmount`  coming from in the expected Result?

Comment: Why is your expected test result not determinant? Also, it doesn't appear that `minAmount` nor `maxAmount` are defined in the test so the expected result in green looks correct to me. Is there more going on in the test suite?

Comment: `typeof minAmount !== 'undefined'`, what are you comparing here? `minAmount` IS `undefined`.